cyclic.sh giving me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
enter image description here
This error is being show on multiple browsers there is nothing in cyclic logs it is not even detecting the request. It sometimes works magically and other times it just does not. I can't  use another hosting platform... . If someone has raised same issues please enlighten us. locally the program works fine
The link to work correctly
